# Dynamically update graph on webpage

Tags: javascript, graph

I have a page where i keep getting data from a database periodically. That data is depicted as a graph. At each period, i want to update the graph with new data. Meaning that i dont want to replace the old graph, but extend it. For example,im using a line chart which is currently displaying. When new data comes in, i want the lines in the chart to extend to represent the new data, but the previous lines should remain as-is. Which JavaScript graphing API can provide this functionality ? Is it possible with Google Charts ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, whether you like it or not, you're in the middle of writing a real-time web application process :D

Here are your solutions:

***Pure javascript***

- If you're in the mood of using a library:

I highly recommend using [APE](http://www.ape-project.org/) library. as I said multiple times before, it's a robust framework for developing real-time web apps.
Another great solution is HTML5's websockets. it's awesome but not cross-browser.

- If you're not in the mood of using a library:

You may send an AJAX request to your server periodically to check whether any updates are available for your data or not.

***Using third party plugins***

The easiest and the most common solution is Adobe Flash's `XMLSocket` APIs.
You may use Silverlight too, but you know, it doesn't worth it (development time I meant).

---

**EDIT:**

Oh, almost forgot to say, this style of programming (updating data without user's interaction/awareness) is called [Comet programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_%28programming%29), so if you need a keyword to search further on this subject use this one.

Comment: @Cygnus your welcome :D developing real-time web apps and Comet programming needs a little bit more effort and work but the result is always better than the classic web apps. good luck.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with 3p3r, and can elaborate on library implementation.

A topic you may want to keep in mind is Data-Binding.
It is a process commonly employed by MVC systems such as backbone.js.
The notion is that the model(data) is automatically updated into the View when data changes are detected .

Data-Binding is not only available in MVC it is also available in graphing widgets for libraries like ExtJS. Using a library can greatly reduce your maintenance overhead in development and avoid commonly encountered complications.

Other libraries that may easily incorporate a data-binding process are: D3, HighCharts, and Raphael.

All the best!
Nash

Comment: Thanks a ton ! I have used data binding in MVC (WPF apps)..didn't know about the web support though !!